# Automate creation of shelveset when getting latest in TFS

Tags: version-control, tfs

Since TFS get-latest operation is non transactional there is no way to abort merging code after issuing get latest. Both Git and ClearCase allows you to backout of rebase operation. So one way I came up with is is to create a shelveset right before I get latest so I can abort and retrieve my code if there's too many conflicts that I don't want to deal with immediately.

My question is is there a way to automate the creation of a shelveset when you do get latest, ideally overwriting an existing one if it exists (say with a hardcoded name "HEAD").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following command will auto shelve current workspace files and get latest:

```
tf shelve "HEAD" /comment:"Autoshelve" /replace /recursive /noprompt&tf get
```

You can store it in a `.cmd` file under your project's root folder in the source control.

Comment: but this wouldn't kick in the resolve conflicts screen in visual studio if i issue this command manually...

Comment: If you don't pass `/noprompt` it would